# Get the value using class name in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the value of an input text field and multiply it by quantity and display on total column.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W7P4S/1/)

**Html**

```
Price: <input id="price" type="text"/>
<table id="my-table">
<tr>
   <td>Quantity</td>
   <td>Total</td>
</tr>   
<tr>
    <td class="quantity">15,447.84</td>
    <td class="total"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="quantity">89.28</td>
    <td class="total"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#price').on('change', calTotal);
    function calTotal() {
        var p = $('#price').val();
        var q = $('.quantity').text();
        alert(q);
    }
});
```

`var q = $('.quantity').text();` give me output as `15,447.8489.28`.

How can I multiply each `quantity` by price and print on total column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Use `parseFloat()` and `.text()` to set the values.
- Also you have two columns for total and quantity each, you need to check values of both the respective columns while assigning the text in `total`
- You need to convert `15,000` to `15000`, use `replace()` for this.

---

```
$('.total').text(function(){
    var q = $(this).prev().text();
    q = q.replace(/,/g, '');                
    p = p.replace(/,/g, '');  
    return (parseFloat(p)*parseFloat(q))
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W7P4S/7/)**

Comment: Thank you very much :). I have little problem. how can i add thousand separators to total and limit to two decimal places ? Check this. http://jsfiddle.net/W7P4S/8/ type 10 for price and see. it show `91.19999999999999`. i need to show it as `91.19` and `154478.4` as `154,478.4`.